# How do I open my third eye?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I need to open my third eye to find the jelly beans hidden in the wall in Shroomcave. I tried eating two mushrooms, as they halfway open it, but that didn't work. I read somewhere I needed the extract from a mushroom, where can I get a mushroom extract to open my third eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the Mushroom Plucking Pliers. I bought mine from Dirtwater Mercantile but they might also be obtainable through a randome event. Then go to the Shroomcave and pluck several *Lactarius Dirtihippica* mushrooms using the pliers. You can also pay 1000 meat to the guy selling "extra groovy" mushrooms in one of the Fort of Darkness tents.

Take those mushrooms to the tent in the Fort of Darkness with the guy standing in front of test tubes and beakers. Talk to the guy and he will change your *Lactarius Dirtihippica* mushrooms into *Dirtihippica* extract.

Drink the extract and go back to the far end of the Shroomcave to reach the room with the jelly beans.

Comment: You also need to read the book 'Mycology, Yourcology' to be able to identify the mushrooms before picking them.